# How do jQuery plugins sort HTML tables?

Tags: jquery, algorithm, html-table

I have a custom table that has a custom format to it, which makes it quite impossible to apply existing table sorting plugins.

How do most plugins accomplish this on a standard HTML table.

Just a basic, simple bullets explanation is fine. Just want to get an idea of how it works.

Comment: [choose your sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), and move the nodes around with `insertBefore` / `appendChild` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I never took a look at the source of such plugin but I think it works that way.

An HTML table is kind of a matrice, you can probably represent it like this :

```
var table = [
 ['Id', 'Name',    'Phone number',   'Email'],
 [2,    'Boris',   '+33686868686',   'ahah@example.com'],
 [1,    'You',      null,            'foo@bar.baz'],
 [5,    'Anyone',   null,            null]
];
```

Using such matrice, you're able to reorder like this:

```
table.sort(function(a, b) {
   return ((a[0] == b[0]) ? 0 : ((a[0] > b[0]) ? 1 : -1));
});
```

Results in:

```
 ['Id', 'Name',    'Phone number',   'Email'],
 [1,    'You',      null,            'foo@bar.baz'],
 [2,    'Boris',   '+33686868686',   'ahah@example.com'],
 [5,    'Anyone',   null,            null]
```

Then, you reorder the rows by moving them using the sorted array.

Obviously, you'll have more complex sort algorithm, but I think basically it is done like this.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to re-build the table. For instance, extract all `tr` elements, run a `.sort` on the the array of rows, passing a custom sorting function inspecting the column of your interest, and re-insert the rows in the sorted order.

Your custom sort function needs only to extract the value you want to compare, and return 0 if they are equal, 1 if the first value is greater, -1 if the second value is greater.

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    var a = parseInt($(a).find('td:first').text(), 10);
    var b = parseInt($(b).find('td:first').text(), 10);

    if(a == b) return 0;
    return a>b ? 1 : -1;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jgHLK/)

Note that if you're using paginated data, you will of course only be able to sort the data that has been sent to the client. In these scenarios, you'd be better of sending an AJAX request to the server populating the table, to request the sorted data, and re-populate the table based on that response, in the same way as if it was a pagination response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to the 'custom format' that you think cannot be sorted using an existing plugin, for example the 'tablesorter' plugin for jQuery is incredibly flexible: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

I've also had great success in the past using the 'sorttable' plugin (no jQuery) which allows you to use a completely custom sort key, so this could be perfect for your setup: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

Comment: My table have a "category row" that also group the content into different categories - so I end up having "special" rows between the contents.

Answer (score -1):

It's quite easy. You can move  element in DOM.
Simple, you can get data from rows into array, sort them and rebuild table.